# Update Excel with protected cells using c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a requirement of updating excel file which has some protected cells in my c# library. But I need to update unprotected cells. No need to even touch any protected cells.
In my current implementation I have used `Excel` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` libraries.

Here is my current implementation.

```
   public void UpdateTableCellAndSave(string fileName , System.Data.DataTable dataTable, int worksheetNumber )
        {
            try
            {

                Application excel = new Application();
                Range excelCellrange;
                Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, false, 5, null, null, false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, null, true, false, 0, true, false, false);
                workbook.Unprotect();
                Sheets worksheets = workbook.Worksheets as Sheets;
                Worksheet worksheet = worksheets.Item[worksheetNumber] as Worksheet;
                worksheet.Unprotect();

                if (worksheet == null)
                    return;

                // loop through each row and add values to our sheet
                int rowcount = 1;

                foreach (DataRow datarow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    rowcount += 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // on the first iteration we add the column headers
                        if (rowcount == 2)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataTable.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                            worksheet.Cells.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                        }

                        worksheet.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();

                        //for alternate rows
                        if (rowcount > 2)
                        {
                            if (i == dataTable.Columns.Count)
                            {
                                if (rowcount % 2 == 0)
                                {
                                    excelCellrange = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[rowcount, 1], worksheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
                excel.Application.Quit();
                excel.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

In this code I am reading all the content of the excel and make any update needs to do and save it in same excel. It is like creating new excel tab by deleting all the content of old sheet.

But in my requirement file has some protected cells that never needs to update and I do not have password for protected cells. So when saving all as new sheet it does not allow coz I am trying to update protected values too.

Can someone help me on this I have no restriction of changing the library also.

Comment: But I see you unprotecting the worksheet? `worksheet.Unprotect()`?

Comment: yes I do it. But it is not working coz of un protect need credentials that I do not know. @SiddharthRout

Comment: **1.** Then why are you using it? What purposes does it serve? **2.** Also why are you writing to all the cells? First identify the cells that you want to write to (should be unprotected) and then save/saveas the file

Comment: @SiddharthRout I need that solution to be implement with above code or with any other way.